# Why im getting file not found exception?

Tags: c#, winforms

In form1 im doing:

```
AnimatedGif.CreateAnimation();
```

AnimatedGif is a new class:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using unfreez_wrapper;
using System.IO;

namespace ScreenVideoRecorder
{
    public static class AnimatedGif
    {
        private static UnFreezWrapper unfreez;
        private static FileInfo[] fi;
        private static DirectoryInfo di;

        public static void CreateAnimation()
        {
            unfreez = new UnFreezWrapper();
            List<string> files = new List<string>();
            di = new DirectoryInfo(@"D:\Testbmp");
            fi = di.GetFiles("*.jpg");
            for (int i = 0; i < fi.Length; i++)
            {
                files.Add(fi[i].Name);
            }
            unfreez.MakeGIF(files, @"D:\Testbmp\Animated.gif", 8, true);
        }

    }
}
```

Before its even getting to the first line in the new class in the method CreateAnimation its throwing exception in form1 on the line:

```
AnimatedGif.CreateAnimation();

Could not load file or assembly 'unfreez_wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found

System.IO.FileNotFoundException was unhandled
  HResult=-2147024770
  Message=Could not load file or assembly 'unfreez_wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
  Source=ScreenVideoRecorder
  FileName=unfreez_wrapper.dll
  FusionLog=""
  StackTrace:
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.AnimatedGif.CreateAnimation()
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Form1.ExitApplication_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Form1.cs:line 200
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.RaiseEvent(Object key, EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripMenuItem.OnClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleClick(EventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.HandleMouseUp(MouseEventArgs e)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEventInteractive(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripItem.FireEvent(EventArgs e, ToolStripItemEventType met)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.OnMouseUp(MouseEventArgs mea)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WmMouseUp(Message& m, MouseButtons button, Int32 clicks)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ScrollableControl.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStrip.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripDropDown.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.OnMessage(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Control.ControlNativeWindow.WndProc(Message& m)
       at System.Windows.Forms.NativeWindow.DebuggableCallback(IntPtr hWnd, Int32 msg, IntPtr wparam, IntPtr lparam)
       at System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.DispatchMessageW(MSG& msg)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ComponentManager.System.Windows.Forms.UnsafeNativeMethods.IMsoComponentManager.FPushMessageLoop(IntPtr dwComponentID, Int32 reason, Int32 pvLoopData)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoopInner(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.ThreadContext.RunMessageLoop(Int32 reason, ApplicationContext context)
       at System.Windows.Forms.Application.Run(Form mainForm)
       at ScreenVideoRecorder.Program.Main() in d:\C-Sharp\ScreenVideoRecorder\ScreenVideoRecorderWorkingVersion\Program.cs:line 18
       at System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.AppDomain.nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[] args)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.Run(Boolean checkAptModel)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ManifestRunner.ExecuteAsAssembly()
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext, String[] activationCustomData)
       at System.Runtime.Hosting.ApplicationActivator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at System.Activator.CreateInstance(ActivationContext activationContext)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssemblyDebugInZone()
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(Object state)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
       at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
       at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
  InnerException:
```

And i see the dll file in my project referenced it and also on my hard disk in the debug and release.

Comment: "Could not load file or assembly 'unfreez_wrapper.dll' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found" is unfreez_wrapper.dll in the right place along with *all* of the other DLL's that it needs?

Comment: Have a look in the folder you are getting the dll from, see if there's any others in there and add them to your project as reference and make sure you set them to copy always / copy if newer.